# Multivariate normal distribution transformation

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, svd, multivariate-distribution

Suppose that $X $ has a multivariate normal distribution 
$X\sim MVN (\mu, \Sigma) $, 
How can I transform $X$ into $Z$ so that $Z\sim MVN(\mu, I) $ where $I$ is the identity matrix?

For instance,  let $\mu= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and the variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.75 & -0.09& 0.33\\
 -0.09 & 0.37& 0.10\\
 0.33 & 0.10& 0.29 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I tried to use the singular value decomposition (SVD) and calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}$ and eigenvectors $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}$, but I do not know how to continue or if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach using SVD is one way to do it. Let $\Sigma$ decomposed by $UDU^{\rm T}$, where $D={\rm diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p)$ and $U$ is a matrix with its columns the eigenvectors. Then, define $K=UD^{1/2}$, which satisfies $KK^{\rm T} = \Sigma$. Now multiply the inverse matrix of $K$ on the original vector $X$, i.e. 
$$K^{-1}(X-\mu) \sim N(0,  K^{-1}\Sigma (K^{-1})^{\rm T}).$$
By noting that $K^{-1}\Sigma (K^{-1})^{\rm T}=I$, we get the desired result.

Comment: Is $K$ a Cholesky factor of $\Sigma$?

Comment: The Cholesky decomposition is based on a lower triangular matrix, so $K$ is not a Cholesky factor.